# How to set default search value to search box on page load with Algolia Search?

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have created my Algolia search in **“localhost/search”** path. I want if some one redirected to that page using **“localhost/search?dog”** type URL , Then the search box should be filed with **dog**. Is that possible to do that?

```
search.addWidget(
 instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
// defaultSearchVal: defaultSearchVal,//Is there a way to add something like this
container: '#search-searchbar',
placeholder: 'Search into posts...', 
poweredBy: true
```

})
);

[image]
I was created this by reading [this algoria example](https://community.algolia.com/jekyll-algolia/blog.html#adding-widgets)

Comment: Since no one gives me answer I have emailed them and they gave me an answer.

Comment: I add the URL for the answer.

Comment: The link doesn't appear to contain the answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to set default search value to search box or retain the value of searchbox on page reload with Algolia Autocomplete.js.

```
initialState: {
  query: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("search")
},
```

In the URL http://localhost?search=dog, **search** is a query parameter.

Here is the complete code for it

```
autocomplete({
    container: '#autocomplete',
    initialState: {
        query: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("search")
    },
    placeholder: 'Search for products',
    getSources() {
        return [];
    },
});
```